# iOS create UIImage with gradient in 4 corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, gradient

I know how to create a gradient UIImage with colors changing from top to bottom. As shown below:

```
[self linearGradientImageFromColors:@[(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor purpleColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor]]



- (UIImage *)linearGradientImageFromColors:(NSArray*)colorArray
{
    CGSize textSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGFloat width = textSize.width;
    CGFloat height = textSize.height;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer.colors = colorArray;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return  image;
}
```

However I am now trying to figure out how to achieve the following type where the color is different in each 4 corner:

[image]

### Edit

I have sort of been able to achieve something closer to what I want by drawing 4 separate images where each image is a gradient of color in one corner and clearColor in the opposite corner and then combine all 4 images to get the result. However this gives me a much different (darker) result than what I want. Where am I going wrong?

**4 corner gradient try code:**

```
[self corneredGradientImageFromColors:@[[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor purpleColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor redColor]]]



- (UIImage *)corneredGradientImageFromColors:(NSArray*)colorArray
{
    CGSize textSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGFloat width = textSize.width;
    CGFloat height = textSize.height;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    //CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CAGradientLayer *layer1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer1.colors = @[(__bridge id)((UIColor*)[colorArray objectAtIndex:0]).CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    layer1.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    layer1.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);
    [layer1 renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imagelayer1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CAGradientLayer *layer2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer2.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)((UIColor*)[colorArray objectAtIndex:1]).CGColor];
    layer2.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
    layer2.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);
    [layer2 renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imagelayer2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CAGradientLayer *layer3 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer3.colors = @[(__bridge id)((UIColor*)[colorArray objectAtIndex:2]).CGColor, (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    layer3.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
    layer3.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);
    [layer3 renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imagelayer3 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CAGradientLayer *layer4 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    layer4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    layer4.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (__bridge id)((UIColor*)[colorArray objectAtIndex:3]).CGColor];
    layer4.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    layer4.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);
    [layer4 renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imagelayer4 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [imagelayer1 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [imagelayer2 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [imagelayer3 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [imagelayer4 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return  result;
}
```

This achieves this:

[image]

### Edit

This is not a duplicate of the one mentioned. I am trying to create a UIImage and the duplicate mentioned neither creates a UIImage nor does that solution work.